# Parallel computing in python: Can't fix this ImportError

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn

I am testing out this simple code in python:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [random.randrange(1,101,1) for _ in range(100)]
    b = [random.randrange(1,101,1) for _ in range(100)]

    d = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b':b})

    temp = StandardScaler().fit_transform(d)

    KM = KMeans(n_jobs=2, n_clusters=5)
    cluster = KM.fit(temp).labels_
```

every time I tried to run it, it generated the following error message:

> ImportError: [joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing without protecting your import on a system that does not support forking. To use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect your main loop using "if **name** == '**main**'". Please see the joblib documentation on Parallel for more information

I think I've already followed the instruction here but don't why this message persists.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Just want to update the status. I was using Spyder 4.0 with python 3.6.5, and constantly got this message. Then I switched to VSCode and the code ran well. After I restarted Spyder, I don't get this error anymore. Well I guess sometimes the best way to fix a problem is to restart your software or computer :)